# How to lookup specific part numbers involved in a NHTSA Recall

Tags: recall

One of my vehicles is facing a [recall](https://static.nhtsa.gov/odi/rcl/2021/RCAK-21V766-7689.pdf) but I'm having trouble substantiating what component is involved exactly in terms of a specific part number. The recall identifies the components involved in a fairly detailed sense but I'm curious why they don't go the route of identifying the specific part number when they can.

> Makes/Models/Model Years: VOLVO/S60/2001-2009 VOLVO/S80/2001-2006
>
> Mfr's Report Date: September 30, 2021
>
> NHTSA Campaign Number: 21V-766
>
> Components: AIR BAGS:FRONTAL:DRIVER SIDE:INFLATOR MODULE

Answer (score 5):

I called up the National Highway Traffic Safety Administration (NHTSA) Vehicle Safety Hotline at 1-888-327-4236 to cross reference whether or not they had the part number on file that they could share with me. They told me that these replacement parts involved in recalls are not off the shelf products that could also suffer the same design flaws as the one to be replaced. They are in fact specially developed parts made by the manufacturer and demonstrated to be adequate to NHTSA to repair the faulty part. So these parts must come from the manufacturer and not be part matched to some inventory from some online retailer or the like. The point isn't to just have a new part installed but rather a newly designed part.